# Using a segment control to update a container view

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, containers, segue

Ok, i've got a view controller with a segmented control and in the container view there is a PFQueryTableviewController.

The reason for all of this is aesthetics and won't be changed i know this can be done by making a tableview in the same view controller, but PFQueryTableViewController doesn't work like this so humour me.

Currently have a segmented control assigning an integer for each segmented choice.

Is there a way when i click on segment control to reload the table view and send the new integer, or a better way of sending integers to the container.

currently using

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

```
var detailScene = segue.destinationViewController as DictionaryTableViewController

detailScene.segmentChoice = segmentChoice
```

}

which only works when the page is loaded, any help would be really appreciated thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you created your container view controller from a storyboard, you can should create an property in your parent view controller that refer to you container view controller.

```
@IBOutlet weak var detailScene: PFQueryTableviewController!
```

That way, you can send the segmented control index like this :

```
self.detailScene.segmentChoice = segmentChoice
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it's calling an instance of the class type and not the class. So i can only access methods inside the class type PFQueryTableViewController. 

`var Controller = detailSceneController as DictionaryTableViewController`

This allows me to access the class type but returns a error which shows it's not producing anything

Comment: I don't follow your explanation. Sorry.